# Want to switch 2 values based on order using awk

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk, sed

I'm pretty unfamiliar with awk/sed/grep and have been working to find a solution to a problem. I have a BIOS config file that looks like this..

```
...

Dual Boot Order #1=0001

Dual Boot Order #2=0002

Dual Boot Order #3=0003

...

Dual Boot Order #15=000E

...
```

What I want to do is detect if a certain value is in the #1 position, and if it isn't, find it later on in the boot order list and switch it with whatever value is currently in the #1 spot. For example if I wanted to prioritize the 000E boot option, I want my output to be..

```
...

Dual Boot Order #1=000E

Dual Boot Order #2=0002

Dual Boot Order #3=0003

...

Dual Boot Order #15=0001

...
```

I am currently storing the value in the #1 in a shell variable and am planning on checking it and basing the next commands on the value of that.

```
temp=$(awk '/Dual Boot Order #1=..../ { if ( $4 != "#1=000E" ) print $4 }' file.txt)
```

I'll also need to save these changes afterwards. Anyone know a more straightforward way of accomplishing this? Thanks!

Comment: Please show the desired output or result that goes with your sample input.

Comment: Basically if I want 000E first, I would want Dual Boot Order #1=000E and Dual Boot Order #15=0001

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's start with this test file:

```
$ cat configfile 
...
Dual Boot Order #1=0001
Dual Boot Order #2=0002
Dual Boot Order #3=0003
...
Dual Boot Order #15=000E
...
```

Now, if we want to swap `000E` into first place:

```
$ awk -v x=000E '$4~x {sub(/=.*/, a, $4)} $4~/#1=/{a=$4; sub(/^[^=]*/, "", a); $4="#1="x} 1' configfile
...
Dual Boot Order #1=000E
Dual Boot Order #2=0002
Dual Boot Order #3=0003
...
Dual Boot Order #15=0001
...
```

If you have GNU awk (gawk) and you want to change the file *in-place*:

```
gawk -i inplace -v x=000E '$4~x {sub(/=.*/, a, $4)} $4~/#1=/{a=$4; sub(/^[^=]*/, "", a); $4="#1="x} 1' configfile
```

#### How it works

- `-v x=000E`

  This defines an awk variable `x` with the value `000E`.
- `$4~x {sub(/=.*/, a, $4)}`

  If the fourth field is a regex  match to `x`, then update it to `a` (the value saved from `#1`).
- `$4~/#1=/{a=$4; sub(/^[^=]*/, "", a); $4="#1="x}`

  If the fourth field is for `#1`, then (a) save its current value to `a` and (b) update its value to `x`.
- `1`

  This is awk's cryptic shorthand for print-the-line.

Comment: Wow, extremely impressive. I have a lot to learn with the sed/awk/grep suite. The use of -v to use the awk variable and the sub function were new to me. Thanks!

Comment: @Devigili Glad it helped.

Answer (score 1):

another similar `awk`

```
$ awk -F= -v OFS="=" -v v="000E" '$2==v{$2=t} $1~/#1$/{t=$2;$2=v} 1' file
...

Dual Boot Order #1=000E

Dual Boot Order #2=0002

Dual Boot Order #3=0003

...

Dual Boot Order #15=0001

...
```